# Jailcoder with SDK 6.0

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ios6

I am new to `iOS`. I was installing latest `XCode` with `SDK 6.0` in it. I have been successfully testing my app developed using `SDK 6.0` on simulator. Now i want to test it on real device without developer program account. To do that, i use `Jailcoder`. I have an `iPhone 3GS`, with `AppSync 5.0+` installed. I have tried `"Quick XCode Patch"` and `"Patch My Project"`. However i still get signing error. It said,

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'

Seems it due to `iOS 6.0 SDK` that has not been supporting `jailbroken` devices. I need some hints and workarounds to deal with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Xcode requires iOS apps to be signed.  However, there is a `plist` file that Xcode uses, where you can change this.  You can tell Xcode that code signing is **not** required.

Check this file:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
```

You can edit it on your Mac with the **Property List Editor** application.

Make sure that in that file, `CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED` is set to `NO`.  You'll probably need to do this each time you install a new iOS SDK (e.g. 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, etc.)

You can find out more about this [on the BigBoss website here](http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission).  BigBoss is one of the popular Cydia repositories for distributing jailbreak apps and tweaks.

Comment: For best results, you want to change three values in there:        `<key>AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED</key>
  <string>YES</string>
  <key>CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED</key>
  <string>NO</string>

  <key>ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED</key>
  <string>NO</string>`

Comment: @TwistedUmbrella, yes, that is what the BigBoss link I posted shows.  If I remember correctly, though, I've never had to **change** the other two settings ... not sure if they always *default* to the proper values, or not.

Comment: "For best results" was in response to the link only covering one at the time the comment was made. They are changed from the defaults but are only meant as a precaution.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with a jailbroken iPhone 4S, solution above didn't work for me.

So for anyone else running into the same error message:
JailCoder does work on XCode 4.5 + Mac OS 10.8.

As an absolute noob I was missing the step 8 from this guide: [Developing for a Jailbroken iPhone A to Z](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-ios-401/):

> ...link the device and computer. Plug your iPhone in and open Xcode.
>   Open Window>Organizer. Select the device from the list on the left
>   hand side, and click “Use for development.” You’ll be prompted for a
>   provisioning website login, click cancel. It’s there to make
>   legitimate provisioning easier, but doesn’t make illegitimate
>   not-provisioning more difficult.

Comment: Yes there is :) Search for text "And finally, to link the device and computer". It's quite hard to see that digit 8, because it's pushed to the right by an image.

Comment: You are right, don't remember what I was doing a year ago, but it was actually very hard for me to find that step 8 when I was addressing your comment. Included the actual solution in my answer. Thanks for this obvious recommendation. It wasn't that obvious to me :)