# Different Xcode versions and jailbroken devices

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, jailbreak

Is it possible to have an Xcode version installed and set up for apps ad hoc distribution, with distribution certificate and provisioning profile and so on, and at the same time to install another Xcode version and patch it with JailCoder or avoid codesigning apps built by that Xcode? I mean, without interfering with the settings of the former Xcode version.

I'd like to test deployment on jailbroken devices but keeping an Xcode with the settings needed for that purpose separately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can install multiple versions of xcode on your computer if you want the same version installed twice... then you will have to change the name of it so your computer doesn't recognize you as having it and will create a new one... or you can copy paste it ... either way yes, you can have multiple versions ...

Comment: And will patching one of the Xcode versions override the development certificates in Keychain Access?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can always install multiple versions of Xcode on one machine by simply choosing a different install location during the installation process (do not accept the default installation location for the second version).

Disabling the requirement to code sign iOS apps is [done by modifying a .plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13260627/119114), that's nested under the install directory for Xcode.  For example, the default location (adjusting for SDK version) is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
```

So, changing this file to modify one Xcode install will have no effect on the other.

Comment: Thanks! And may patching one of the versions with JailCoder affect the development certificates in Keychain for the other version?

Comment: @AppsDev, That part, I do not know, since I don't use jailcoder.  Sorry.